# How can I make route optional parameter "dynamic"?

Tags: routes

I have a route which need to have the `language code` as optional parameter:

```
my_module.my_route:
  path: '/custom-link/{langcode}'
 defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController:render'
```

I know from [Optional parameters](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes#s-optional-parameters) how to make a *static* optional parameter.

However, I need to determine the parameter dynamically: if it is not provided in the url, it should be the site's default language.

How can I implement that?

Comment: You could use a static default value `not-defined` and when your controller receives this value it replaces it dynamically.

Comment: You should make that an answer.

Comment: It's a bit too simple, just an alternative if there is no dynamic default route parameter within the routing system, a callback for example.

Comment: @4uk4: thanks for the suggestion. Alas, I don't understand "just an alternative if there is no dynamic default route parameter within the routing system, a callback for example". Is there that possibility, or is a comment about the lack of that feature in Drupal?

Comment: I don't know if there is that possibility. If not it could be a valid feature request in cases where the controller code is not custom.